# sort list with C# by how often same strings appear in list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, linq, sorting

I have a list:

```
dave
maggie
john
stuart
john
john
dave
john
maggie
maggie
```

My desired result would be:

```
john
john
john
john
maggie
maggie
maggie
dave
dave
stuart
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Nested string list in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547077/sort-a-nested-string-list-in-c-sharp)

Comment: you can put your logic , the hint is given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211194/count-occurrences-of-words-in-arraylist

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First I group them. Then order them by the count from each group. Lastly use `SelectMany` to get a flat structure from each individual name in the groups.

```cs
var myList = new List<string>()
{
    "dave",
    "maggie",
    "john",
    "stuart",
    "john",
    "dave",
    "john",
};

var result = myList
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
    .SelectMany(x => x)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Stefan yes. `SelectMany` takes a function returning a `IEnumerable<T>` and `GroupBy` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`.